# Redeclaring variables in C

Tags: c

I've seen a similar question asked wrt c++, [Does redeclaring variables in C++ cost anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783633/does-redeclaring-variables-in-c-cost-anything)

But what about C? Will redeclaring a variable in C have any noticeable affect? Is this generally considered bad code organization?

```
for(;;) {
   int y = 1 + 2 + 3; // some kind of repeated redeclaration? 
}
```

EDIT:

Enhancing my ask.

If I have a loop in a function, would calling 'int y = 1 + 2 + 3;' over and over again be allowed? Will it cause problems? What does it do, declare `y` once?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking.  If your question whether declaring int y in a loop costs more than outside of the loop -- no, it doesn't.

Comment: @CinCout of course you can.

Comment: You can give a variable in a local scope the same name as the variable in a global scope though.  In this case, you wouldn't be able to access the global variable y inside the loop

Comment: Improved my question.

Comment: The answers to the other question discuss the issue in great detail. There are no significant differences between C and C++ in this regard. In C++, if your type is not `int` but a user-defined type with overloaded operations, things become more complicated, but that shouldn't bother you for C. Your example is a bit pointless, though, as the code inside the loop (1) does not depend on the iteration count and (2) has no effect anyway.

Comment: @5gon12eder, The loop isn't really important. They could just be sequential redeclerations. `int y = 1; int y = 2; int y = 3;` What happens here is my question.

Comment: That later example would be a semantic error and rejected by the compiler. It is important to agree upon what example we're discussing. Especially if you are *not* sure what the code does exactly.

Comment: Ok to improve my question to you. Why is it not a semantic error in my for loop example?

Comment: There is no disallowed redeclaration in the example in your question because there is only a single declaration to begin with. I suspect your question is actually more about *scope* than performance.

Comment: I think what I'm asking in my edit is pretty clear. What happens when that particular line is called in a loop, the first time, and subsequent times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C language has the concept of *variable scope*. Ina a nutshell, each pair of `{` and `}` introduce new scope, and variables are bound to those scopes. You can declare variables with the same name, as long they are in different scopes.

That's why you that's valid:

```
if(...) {
    int y; # y is valid here
}          # end of scope, y is not valid here
if(...) {  # new scope
    int y; # That's another y
}
```

And that's not valid:

```
if(...) {
    int y;
    int y; # error, redeclaration
}
```

Moreover *declaration* is a source code property, not runtime program property.

So, if you write:

```
for(;;) {
   int y = 1 + 2 + 3;
}
```

You declare `y` *once* (because you have written it once), not infinite number of times.

Comment: You write/declare it once in the static C code; but at runtime, its declaration is passed and its initialization is performed many times. All modern mainstream compilers would pull that constant declaration out of the loop (and as soon as the most modest optimization is enabled, eliminate all of y from the code); but conceptually, y's scope is left with each iteration, and y is initialized over and over again each time the control flow passes the declaration.

Answer (score 8):

Most C compilers optimize everything away that they can.

If you want to really find out, compile with the flag to look at the assembly code and see what it's doing. Like someone said, if it's a simple type (doesn't have a constructor), and particularly if you're using all literals, the compiler will probably just move a fixed value into a register each iteration, or not even bother, if nothing changes the variable between iterations

I just checked your example as shown below, and also changed it to modify a variable in the loop, and you can see how the assembly code generated changes.

In the first example, notice the loop at LBB0_1, it's just a movl instruction.

In the 2nd example, it's still pretty simple, but even though the results aren't used, it still saves things on the stack. I added some comments to explain what the loop is doing.

**$ cc -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -S dummy.c**

```
int main(void) { 
    for(;;) {
        int y = 1 + 2 + 3;
    }
}
```

**$ cat dummy.s**

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 12
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movl    $6, -8(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1

.subsections_via_symbols
```

**$ cc -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -S dummy.c**

```
int main(void) { 
    int i = 0;
    for(;;) {
        int y = i + 2 + 3;
        i++;
    }
}
```

**$ cat dummy.s**

```
        .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .macosx_version_min 10, 12
        .globl  _main
        .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
## BB#0:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)            
        movl    $0, -8(%rbp)            ## i = 0
LBB0_1:                                 
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax          ## y = i
        addl    $2, %eax                ## y += 2
        addl    $3, %eax                ## y += 3
        movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)         ## -12(rbp) = y
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax          ## eax = i
        addl    $1, %eax                ## i++
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## -8(rbp) = i
        jmp     LBB0_1

.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Thanks- this is very useful to know how to do.